# Apache POI date dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have problems to get date in right format using apache poi 3.7
According the documentation I have to use the formatCellValue Method from DataFormatter.
Here I found a few answers which advise the same, but it don´t works.

The excel field shows the date in format `dd.MM.yyyy`: for ex: `09.06.2010`

After using formatCellValue(Cell cell) I get 9/6/10.
I try DataFormatter and HSSFDataFormatter with and without Local.German or Local.German

Here is my code:

```
if( DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
{
    HSSFDataFormatter formatter = new HSSFDataFormatter(Locale.GERMAN);
    String temp = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: "format dd-MM-yyyy: for ex: 09.06.2010" - this doesn't make sense, as the format string and the example date are not compatible! What format string are you really using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain, but I think the issue might be that you've overridden the format string of one of the default date formats.

This was only fixed in POI 3.8 beta 1 (see the [changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)), so I'd suggest you try upgrading to 3.8 beta3 and it will hopefully fix your issue. Previously POI just assumed that the default formats wouldn't have been changed, so would use the default format string for them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The update to POI 3.8 beta 3 don´t help.
I have checked the format of the column in excel. The type is dd.MM.yyyy, but it is marked with an asterriks, what means that the format is dependent on the regional info of the operating system. Maybe this could be the reason.

Comment: Maybe try setting it explicitly then?

Comment: has anyone solved this yet? The excel that is being read is not in our control. and hence if the Date format is specified as above using astrriks(*) It is defaulted to OS level locale. Is there no way where we can override the DataFormater to take our own format?